# Requesting file directly with Node JS server returns with nothing

Tags: node.js, file, http, request, response

So I am trying to get a node js server to serve a file.  Even when I call the file directly in the url (http://localhost:8080/media/file.mp3) it returns no data.  When I console.log on the write statement, it returns false, meaning that some or all the of the data isn't being flushed out and sent to the client.

The code:

```
http.createServer(function(req, res){
res.on('end',()<= {
    if (req.url.includes("media")){
        res.setHeader('Content-Type','audio/mp3');
        res.setHeader('Retry-After', '1');
        res.setHeader('method','POST');
        res.setHeader('Connection','keep-alive');
        res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'audio/mp3'});
        console.log("/path_to_file_from_root_to_index"+req.url);
        fs.readFile("/path_to_file_from_root_to_index"+req.url,function(err,data){
            if (err){
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                res.write(data);
                res.end();
            }
        });
}).listen(8080);
```

What is being shown in the browser when req.url='/media/file.mp3':

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    http = require('http'),
    path = require('path');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {

    if (req.url.includes('media')) {

        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'audio/mp3'
        });
        console.log(path.join(__dirname, '/path_to_file_from_root_to_index' + req.url));
        fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, '/path_to_file_from_root_to_index' + req.url), function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                res.end(data);
            }
        });
    }

}).listen(8080);
```